# apache zepplelin shows ava.lang.classnotfoundexception: com.mysql.jdbc.driver error

Tags: jdbc, apache-zeppelin

```
   name                            value
  common.max_count                  1000
  default.driver                   org.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 default.password                    ****
  default.url                     jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
 default.user                      root
zeppelin.interpreter.localRepo    /usr/local/zeppelin/local-repo/2DCVRUUK8
zeppelin.interpreter.output.limit   102400
zeppelin.jdbc.auth.type     
zeppelin.jdbc.concurrent.max_connection     10
zeppelin.jdbc.concurrent.use                true

 Dependencies
   artifact                                                        exclude
 /usr/local/zeppelin/interpreter/jdbc/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar
```

These are my interpreter settings. I have loaded mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar with correct path, then I am still unable to run this.

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, if anyone is trying to access mysql table using spark as below

```
val tempDF = spark.read.jdbc(<JdbcConnectionURL>, "table_name", <ConnectionProperties>)      
tempDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tempdf")
tempDF.show(10,false)
```

And encounters `com.mysql.jdbc.driver` error due to missing dependency then we can add the mysql-connector as dependency on spark interpreter as mentioned by @cricket_007

[image]

or by calling the below deprecated command on the first paragraph of zeppelin notebook

```
%dep

z.load("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.11")
```

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin can just use Maven targets

Add this

```
mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.46
```

Restart the interpreter

Comment: I would like to connect to mysql using spark, adding this dependency in spark interpret would help resolve mysql jdbc connector ?